# Some confusing problems in reversing with IDA about gs segment

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, reverse-engineering, ida

Once I used IDA Pro to disassemble an ELF and I found some code like

`*mk_fp(\__gs__,12)` or `*mk_fp(\__gs__,8)` and so on.

What does this mean? Does it mean something about system calls or function calls?

Thanks a lot for some help

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `mk_fp` means *make far pointer*, as such these can be IDA's idea of decompiling `gs:[12]` and `gs:[8]` respectively.

In 64 bit kernel `gs` segment is used for storing per-cpu kernel data. In 32 bit user mode, it is generally used for thread local storage.

Comment: is the address inTLS fixed or not?

Comment: The address of the TLS is not fixed, each thread has its own, of course. The offsets inside the TLS are the same, so each thread can access its own set of values. A particular implementation (eg. `libc`) defines the layout.